# Plots of Wannier Functions on the Triangular Lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body

I have been looking for quite a long time on the internet for simple plots of Wannier functions (and/or their squares) for a two dimensional potential forming a triangular lattice. A parametrisation of the potential would be
$$V_{a,V_0}(x,y)=V_0\left(\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{a}x-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}a}y)+\sin^2(\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}a}y)+\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{a}x+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}a}y)\right)$$
with $V_0$ the potential depth and $a$ the lattice constant.

I am familiar with the calculation of wannier function using the Fourier space representation of the wave functions. I am mainly interested in seeing already calculated Wannier functions, as I would like to have a comparison for my numerical calculations. Maybe somebody of you has a nice reference where such a function is depicted.